# how to apply pagination in this case using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

i got the annonces from a user authenticator, and i want to do pagination but i don't know how.

**UsersController.php**

```
public function index()
    {
        $annonces = Auth::user()->annonces;
        $users = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
         return view('users.index')->with([
             'users'        => $users,
             'annonces'     => $annonces
         ]);
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to paginate announces list? Do announces is a relationship, if so please include that code too

Comment: @JitendraYadav thank you for your answer but the relationship it works well and the list of announcements is displayed well it remains just pagination, and I do not know if I need to include the relationship code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function index()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    $annonces = $user->annonces()->paginate(5);

    return view('users.index', [
        'user' => $user,
        'annonces' => $annonces
    ]);
}
```